# How to send data as multipart in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send data to the backend in (multipart) form-data  format where one is data in that I have to pass JSON and the other is file where I have to pass the file

Answer (score 0):

```
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('data', JSON.stringify(getVendorData));
  fd.append('file', JSON.stringify(this.image));

   return this.http
    .post(`${this.testingServer}`, query, {
      responseType: 'json'
    })
    .pipe(
      retry(3)
    );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?